# checking for duplicate email and user name in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-membership

I have to check for duplicate email and user name in this unit test. Speaking with another developer, he said I should check for the duplicate email and user name in a nested try catch. Im not sure I understood him correctly or not but here is what I have. The other developer isnt available right now, so I cant ask to verify. Im thinking this format isnt correct. Any advice?

```
        try
        {

            AsaMembershipProvider prov = this.GetMembershipProvider();


            MembershipCreateStatus status;
            MembershipUser user = prov.CreateUser("UserX", "12345", "UserX@abc.com", "", "", true, null, out status);


            user = prov.GetUser("UserX", false);


            var isAuthenticated = prov.ValidateUser(user.UserName, "12345");
            Assert.IsTrue(isAuthenticated);
            Assert.AreEqual(user.UserName, "UserX");
            Assert.AreEqual(user.Email, "userx@abc.com");

            try
            {

                prov.DeleteUser("UserX", true);

                user = prov.GetUser("UserX", false);

                Assert.AreEqual(null, user);
                user = prov.GetUser("UserX", false);


                Assert.AreEqual(status, MembershipCreateStatus.Success);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogMessage(ex);
                Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
            }


            prov.DeleteUser("UserX", true);

            user = prov.GetUser("UserX", false);

            Assert.AreEqual(null, user);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogMessage(ex);
            Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your question is a little vague, but that *is* a nested try catch (try/catch within a try/catch) if that's really all you're asking. Is there a problem with your implementation? Errors/unexpected result?

Comment: I'm going to make two assumptions here: 1) Users are being stored in a  database. 2) The users table has a unique index on email. You should probably create a user twice with the same email, and expect your database client to throw an appropriate exception thanks to the unique index.

Comment: As it was explained to me, the nested try catch should throw an exception when it finds the duplicate email and then the test should continue, but it stops there.

Comment: If that's the expected behavior, you should not call `Assert.Fail(ex.Message);`

Comment: so the arrest should be .IsTrue?

Comment: You can use `Assert.Throws`, passing it a delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code in the try block to a call to `Assert.Throws<T>`:

```
Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => {
    // attempt to create a duplicate user.
}, "Exception thrown when creating duplicate user.");
```

Change `Exception` to the exact exception type you expect to be thrown when a duplicate is created.